# How to do git hub configuration?

Tags: github, version-control

I am a new user to git hub. I just wanted to configure my GitHub account from the git bash. What is the command that should be used to configure username? Please help me to solve this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **git config** command to that

```
$ git config --global user.name "P.Mihiran"
```

From the above command, it sets the user name as you mentioned. If you want to check the username you can use the following command to check user name

```
git config --global user.name
```

For more details visit 
https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-your-username-in-git